# Why is compression not recommended in OpenVPN?

Tags: vpn, encryption, openvpn, compression

In latest stable OpenVPN series, 2.5, all compression-related directives are considered deprecated. From [wiki page](https://community.openvpn.net/openvpn/wiki/DeprecatedOptions?__cf_chl_jschl_tk__=8P9gdG6IPOL6Qt18GJIfkbPEahMvJdkkSfaAxZ7rte0-1636526786-0-gaNycGzNBtE#Option:--comp-lzo):

> Compression is not recommended and is a feature users should avoid
> using. To signal this clearly, `--comp-lzo` and `--compress` are
> discouraged and considered deprecated features. Beginning with 2.5,
> these options will no longer enable compression, just enable the
> compression framing to be able to receive compressed packets.

Basically, these options now are made "noop" commands.

Why? Especially in spite of the fact *compression is recommended* before encryption, because it removes the redundancy from the data and therefore makes it overall to look more random (see e.g. [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4399812/is-it-better-to-encrypt-a-message-and-then-compress-it-or-the-other-way-around) on the S.O.). What's the problem?

Comment: I think the comparison of PGP compression to OpenVPN compression is not a good one. My impression of how the Internet works is many services — such as web sites — already do Gzip compression as a default. So compression on top of that is a waste of resources even if just to check if there is compressed content.

Comment: PGP has nothing to do with this recommendation, which is generic and applies to any compression and any encryption. Primary use of VPN  is not to browse web sites or other Internet services, but to allow remote employee to use internal office services and to connect office sites with each other. It makes the impression of the LAN, where often highly-compressable data is sent over the wire, so it'll likely benefit from the compression. Your comment makes no sense.

Comment: Re "compression is recommended before encryption", if you found this in any relatively new text, then the emphasis isn't on "encryption is recommended" (all modern encryption algorithms are equally strong whether the data is compressed or not and don't care about how random the input data looks) – the emphasis is on "before", as opposed to "after" (if the encryption algorithm is strong, the _output_ encrypted data is "random-looking" and therefore incompressible). IOW, compressing the data after encryption is useless, but not compressing it at all is just fine.

Comment: I understand why it is set in this order. I meant other thing. Uncompressed, low-entropy data is conversely highly systematic, and there are concerns that such input into cryptosystem exposes it at risk. This was also considered as the drawback of the CTR block mode, which encrypts very systematic stream of consecutive integers and so exposes cryptosystem at risk in a similar way. By compressing we reduce this systematicity, which is why it is recommended. In turned out compression schemes, as well as encryption schemes, are not perfect and leave birthmarks, which you can exploit...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Compression is not recommended because it makes the connection vulnerable to [oracle attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oracle_attack), specifically Compression Oracle Attacks. This is mentioned in the OpenVPN docs in the ["openvpn" manpage](https://manpages.debian.org/testing/openvpn/openvpn.8.en.html), under "Protocol Options":

> Security Considerations
>
> Compression and encryption is a tricky combination. If an attacker knows or is able to control (parts of) the plain-text of packets that contain secrets, the attacker might be able to extract the secret if compression is enabled. [...]

Basically, if an attacker can influence the plaintext data being sent via the VPN, they can observe the change in compressed size (due to the data being more or less compressible) and find out something about the data, even though it is encrypted.

See e.g. [Compression Oracle Attacks on VPN Networks](https://i.blackhat.com/us-18/Wed-August-8/us-18-Nafeez-Compression-Oracle-Attacks-On-Vpn-Networks.pdf) (Nafeez) for details, and [commit a59fd147](https://github.com/OpenVPN/openvpn/commit/a59fd147) in the OpenVPN Github repository.

Comment: Thank you. This (relatively new) CPA was unknown to me and I somewhat forgot to refresh the manual (which I read often, but I expected to see the explanation in the deprecation statement).

Comment: There have been a couple of famous compression oracle attacks on TLS, HTTPS, and HTTP/2: CRIME, TIME, BREACH, and HEIST, among others. As a result, TLS deprecated compression a while ago, and TLS v1.3 removes support for compression completely.